# In TeX Live 2023, how can I make `tlmgr` honour setting `verify-repo = 1` in its configuration file?

Tags: texlive, tlmgr, repositories, security, texlive-2023

I have been setting `verify-repo` to `all` in `tlmgr`'s configuration file for some time. Having just installed TeX Live 2023, I did this for the new release. I then tried to confirm the value was set correctly using `tlmgr shell` with `get verify-repo`. I got the value `0`.

I then tried setting the value in the configuration file to `none` and to `main`. The value returned in `tlmgr shell` remained `0` in both cases.

I thought perhaps the configuration file wasn't being read, so I tried putting `3` as the value. In that case `tlmgr shell` immediately complains the value is illegitimate. So clearly the file is read. Why doesn't it seem to have any effect on the value which is active?

```
$ cat /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-config/tlmgr/config
verify-repo = all
$ tlmgr shell
tlmgr> protocol 1
tlmgr> get verify-repo
verify-repo = 0
OK
```

Note that I'm not certain what the value `0` means since the recognised values are supposed to be `all`, `main` and `none`.

Note also that the documentation is not entirely consistent and sometimes suggests using `require-verification = 1`, even though this variable is obsolete (and causes `tlmgr shell` to complain).

Comment: it would be imho better to ask on the texlive mailing list.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This does seem odd then? It's not just me?

Comment: Welcome back cfr!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Thanks!